# How to integrate $\int (\tan x)^{1/ 6} \,\text{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How do I compute the following integral

> $$
> I=\int (\tan x)^{1/ 6} \,\text{d}x
> $$

Comment: You are right to be stuck: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28tan+x%29%5E%281%2F6%29+dx

Comment: set $t=\tan(x)$

Comment: @EmilioNovati I'm amazed it even *has* an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: I was thinking of trying to solve this. but now I won't even try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you said you "won't even try" to solve this integral, try *Mathematica*:

$$\frac{-2 \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{-2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[6]{\tan
   (x)}+\sqrt{3}-1}{1+\sqrt{3}}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2} \sqrt[6]{\tan
   (x)}\right)-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt[6]{\tan (x)}+1\right)+2
   \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[6]{\tan
   (x)}+\sqrt{3}-1}{1+\sqrt{3}}\right)-2 \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(-2
   \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}} \sqrt[6]{\tan (x)}+\sqrt{3}+2\right)+2 \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\right) \sqrt[6]{\tan (x)}+\sqrt{3}+2\right)-2 \log
   \left(\sqrt[3]{\tan (x)}-\sqrt{2} \sqrt[6]{\tan (x)}+1\right)+2 \log
   \left(\sqrt[3]{\tan (x)}+\sqrt{2} \sqrt[6]{\tan (x)}+1\right)-\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)
   \log \left(2 \sqrt[3]{\tan (x)}+\sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \sqrt[6]{\tan
   (x)}+2\right)+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \log \left(2 \sqrt[3]{\tan (x)}-2
   \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}} \sqrt[6]{\tan (x)}+2\right)+\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right) \log \left(2
   \sqrt[3]{\tan (x)}+\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}\right) \sqrt[6]{\tan
   (x)}+2\right)-\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \log \left(2 \sqrt[3]{\tan
   (x)}+\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\right) \sqrt[6]{\tan (x)}+2\right)}{4 \sqrt{2}}$$

...just in case you need the answer.

Comment: Who is the "you" in your first sentence?  The OP is user10379 and the one who made the "I was thinking of trying to solve this. but now I won't even try" comment is Nikunj.

Comment: Ah... yes... Nikunj.

Answer (score 3):

The final answer maybe complicated as mentioned in the comments. But here are the steps that you may take to get there.

First use  the substitution $\tan x=u$ and then use another substitution $u=t^6$ to get

$$\begin{align}
I &= \int (\tan x)^{\frac 16} dx \\
&= \int \frac{u^{\frac 16}}{1+u^2} du \\
&= \int \frac{5t^6}{1+t^{12}} dt \\
&= 5 \int \frac{t^6}{1+t^{12}} dt
\end{align}$$

For tackling down the last integral you should use partial fractions. You may wonder that the denominator has no real roots. The answer is that the partial fraction decomposition works for complex roots as well.

Answer (score 0):

HINT (the integral will become very very big):

$$\int\left(\tan(x)\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\space\text{d}x=\int\sqrt[6]{\tan(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\tan(x)$ and $\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}=\sec^2(x)$:

---

$$\int\frac{\sqrt[6]{u}}{1+u^2}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $s=\sqrt[6]{u}$ and $\frac{\text{d}s}{\text{d}u}=\frac{1}{6\sqrt[6]{u^5}}$:

---

$$\int\frac{5s^6}{1+s^{12}}\space\text{d}s=5\int\frac{s^6}{1+s^{12}}\space\text{d}s=$$
$$5\int\left[\frac{s^6+s^2}{3(s^8-s^4+1)}-\frac{s^2}{3(s^4+1)}\right]\space\text{d}s=$$
$$5\left[\int\frac{s^6+s^2}{3(s^8-s^4+1)}\space\text{d}s-\int\frac{s^2}{3(s^4+1)}\space\text{d}s\right]=$$
$$5\left[\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{s^6+s^2}{s^8-s^4+1}\space\text{d}s-\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{s^2}{s^4+1}\space\text{d}s\right]=$$
$$5\left[\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{s^6+s^2}{s^8-s^4+1}\space\text{d}s-\frac{1}{3}\int\left[-\frac{s}{2\sqrt{2}\left(-s^2+\sqrt{2}s-1\right)}-\frac{s}{2\sqrt{2}\left(s^2+\sqrt{2}s+1\right)}\right]\space\text{d}s\right]$$